# How to realloc the words of array?

Tags: c

So the user is going to enter unknown amount of words,, i assume each words is has max length 10;
I got the lvalue required as left operand of assignment  erorr from the realloc.
I am new to C and i tried google but can't find useful answer.

Code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    #define CAPACITY 10
    #define NUM_OF_WORDS 10
    int main(void)
    {

    char *word= malloc(10*sizeof(char));
    char *w[NUM_OF_WORDS];

    int i;
    int n;

    for(i = 0 ; scanf("%s", word)==1; ++i)
    {

    if( i == NUM_OF_WORDS-1)
    w = realloc(w, (NUM_OF_WORDS*=2) * sizeof(char));

    w[i] = malloc( strlen(word)+1 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(w[i], word);
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. NUM_OF_WORDS is constant, it cannot be assigned.
2. w should not use array, should use char **
3. In realloc, you should use sizeof(char *)

Modified Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CAPACITY 10
#define NUM_OF_WORDS 10

int main(void)
{

    char word[10];
    char **w = (char **) malloc(NUM_OF_WORDS * sizeof(char *));

    int i;
    int capacity = NUM_OF_WORDS;

   for(i = 0 ; scanf("%s", word)==1; ++i)
   {

       if( i == capacity -1)
           w = (char **)realloc(w, (capacity *=2) * sizeof(char *));

       w[i] = (char *)malloc( strlen(word)+1 * sizeof(char));
       strcpy(w[i], word);
   }

   // at last, release w and w's element.
   while ( --i >= 0 )
   {
        free(w[i]);
   }

   free( w );       
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to use `realloc()`, you'll need to allocate the array `w` using `malloc()` instead of declaring it on the stack.

Comment: THank you for your time.
I dont understand what you meant by declaring it on the stack?

Comment: Instead of `char *w[NUM_OF_WORDS]`, you want `char *w[] = malloc(NUM_OF_WORDS * WORD_LENGTH);` where WORD_LENGTH is the maximum length of each word in the array (i.e. 10). When you declare the first way, the compiler puts the array on the stack, where it can't be resized. If you allocate the array using `malloc()` the memory will be taken from the heap, where it can be resized. The stack and the heap are two parts of memory that are used in different ways -- explanations are easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

```
w = realloc(w, (NUM_OF_WORDS*=2) * sizeof(char));
```

Regarding the error -

(NUM_OF_WORDS*=2) after preprocessing is (10 *=2).  You cannot assign product of 10*2 to 10. 10 is an rvalue and it cannot be assigned any thing which is what compiler is complaining about. You proabably meant (NUM_OF_WORDS * 2)